# using docker --link to mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, hyperlink

I need to be able to connect to te next docker db:

```
sudo docker run --name=cmydatabse -v /opt/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword" mysql:5.7
```

using a link command, I want to create a link so I can connect to this database using:

```
       mysql -u -p -h  Something  P:3306
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links are legacy from docker compose 2 and all recent docker versions.

The way to link your mysql container is using networks https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks.

With a network the containers will recognize each other by the container name